# Could the power of PR disaster keep the military from creating a robot with an onboard AI

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, society, artificial-intelligence, military

If I want humans to fight alongside robots, I have to take care of the competition first.

According to the lore of my world, only 58 robots were ever created with an onboard artificial intelligence.

The reason for this was massive PR disaster surrounding their creation, mostly in the form of *"Haven't you seen The Matrix/Terminator/I Robot/WALL-E"* (yes, I have) and *"10/10, would cause the end of humankind again."* comments, despite the robots' psychology, being indistinguishable from humans'. Another detail is, this all happened during peacetime.

**Is there any real-life example of the military not doing something because of the PR backlash? Is this scenario possible?**

Comment: Most of our missiles have a form of AI (however limited).  We already had drones and guided missiles in WW1.  The reality is, the military tells you what they want you to know, but they do whatever they want.  Enigma was cracked by a secret "computer" that was only recently revealed.

Comment: Is an *expected*  backlash acceptable? Real generals (outside of movies) tend to be pretty smart about managing risk in the use of decisive power, and about the the political ramifications of controversial weapon systems. Note also western real-world generals prefer human-selected, -approved, or -supervised targeting systems precisely to avoid all manner of unexpected consequences. Good military planning is not about firepower (plenty of that around) - it's about achieving the goal with a minimum of undesirable first-order and second-order effects.

Comment: What is PR? I don't see a fit with Public Relation...

Comment: The short answer is "yes". See, e.g., the Hindenburg.

Answer (score 2):

For a time yes, this seems perfectly reasonable. However eventually if you have one or two robots (which you likely will) then the military will point out that "hey these robot things haven't killed anyone yet. We think we should deploy them on mass" and at some-point the public will agree.

Today it's known that the military will DO things to prevent PR backlash, of course they will as long as they are subservient to a democratic government. For instance the U.S. military produces FAR more than it needs in terms of tanks Mainly because the announcement that "Thousands of U.S. Workers made redundant" doesn't sit well with to public.

Vietnam is a good example of PR backlash effecting military behaviour. Had it not been for the many protests and the general anti-war feeling of the time it's likely america would have stayed until the war was won.

That being said it's unlikely that the automation of warfare would ever be so greatly feared by the public to that extent. In general people can tell the difference between the terminator and real life. People today also generally tend to be pro-technology using it all the time in their day to day life and everyone wants to be ahead of the enemy in these sorts of areas So i'd advise adding in your story a reason that the public is so anti-robot warriors. This could be a early mistake in AI soldiers (think drones accidentally attacking civilian targets without authorisation) or perhaps major figures speak out against the use of robots in war, such as Stephen hawking in our world. Perhaps it becomes a partisan issue and the anti-robot party has enough support in other areas to keep the army human.

Comment: How overwhelmingly monstrous would an accident have to be to halt the production of the robots for a good chunk of time?

Comment: It doesn't really need to be monstrous it just needs to resonate with the public. I.e. if robots attacked the white house live on public TV they'd probably only need to kill one or two people. meanwhile if it's on the other side of the world in an active war zone it'd take a few villages to have a similar affect.  certainly anything the size of 9/11 would do you for a decade or two. (as actual 9/11 did for us and security culture.)

Comment: Would it matter if someone uploaded the carnage on Liveleak?

Comment: @Ummdustry Your use of 9/11 as a test case is acutlly probably very useful.  It vilified a people, making them "the enemy."  You'd probably have to make AI "the enemy" to get this sort of effect, so looking at how we responded to 9/11 would probably be very useful for exploring this AI question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of chemical weapons:  they were forbidden after WWI, and were only rarely used in WWII.  There would have been uses for it, such as strategic bombing of factories with a combination of explosives and persistent chemical agents.

Comment: It's worth noting that chemical weapons are banned as a result of international treaty not as a result of the PR backlash (though there certainly is one).